How to show a native histogram from prometheus on grafana
I have a prometheus cluster with where native histogram enabled and data being generated
the query on prometheus graph is visible correctly as shown below

But the same query in grafana is different as show below


Your screenshots, contrary to your statement in text, do not show the same query.
